# angular2: Error:(62, 33) TS2339: Property 'resolveAndCreate' does not exist on type 'typeof Injector'

Tags: angular

Ever since ng2 beta 17 I get: Error:(62, 33) TS2339: Property 'resolveAndCreate' does not exist on type 'typeof Injector'.

```
  var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate(
        [
            TodoService,
            TodoAction,
            HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            TodoStatsModel,
            provide(CommBroker, {useClass: CommBroker}),
            provide(AppStore, {useValue: this.appStore})
        ]);
```

I can't find an example of how to fix. Any help is appreciated

regadrs

Sean

Comment: The same problem in angular 2.0.0-rc.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

found it:

```
var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(
        [
            TodoService,
            TodoAction,
            HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            TodoStatsModel,
            provide(CommBroker, {useClass: CommBroker}),
            provide(AppStore, {useValue: this.appStore})
        ]);
    this.service = injector.get(TodoService);
```

Comment: Also remember to change your import statement from Injector to ReflectiveInjector